# How to view data in glassfish database without netbeans

Tags: database, netbeans, glassfish-4.1

It is possible to view data in glassfish database without open Netbeans? In command prompt we only can starting and stopping the glassfish but cannot view the database right ?

Answer (score 0):

The database that GlassFish uses is Apache Derby.

There are tools available to browse it, like [SQuirreL SQL Client](https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/SQuirreL_Derby.html) which is detailed on the Apache Derby site, or [RazorSQL](https://razorsql.com/features/derby_gui_tools.html) which I found through a Google search.

Whichever tool you choose, the Derby installation can be found in `$GFHome/glassfish4/javadb/`

**Edit:** If you wanted to browse the database through the command line, you could use `ij` which is found in `$GFHome/glassfish4/javadb/bin/ij`. [There are some basic instructions here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/tools/ttoolsij97656.html).